# ASP.NET ReportViewer Datasource connectionstring not supplied from web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, rdlc

I have created an ASP.NET Empty Web Application in VS 2012 using the .NET Framework 4.5.  I have also added a report to this project.  Inside the Web.Config I have set my connection string.

When working on the report I do not have an option to add a DataSource like I do when working in Windows Form Application.  I want to connect this web app to a object from a library.

Edit:  Why can we not access Object Datasource Type when the a library reference is added to the project?  Why does a helper class have to be added to access the library objects.  Here is what has to be done to achieve this: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
```

`dt` would be your dataTable

EDIT:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
    <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="Report1.rdlc" ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: I don't want to do a runtime design of the RDLC.  I want to be able to design my RDLC at compile time.

Comment: than use the wizard in visual studio, whats the problem

Comment: you can't it that way.  That's why

Comment: Ok so what your trying t to achieve im lost now

Comment: My connection string is encrypted so I can't use a database as my connection source.  I go through an Object Data Source Type.  I was not able to access the within a web application the object library whereas I can within a windows form application.

Comment: If you you add that to the aspx.cs file then go to the rdlc designer for that report file.  Will you be able to work with it?  Programmatically(run time) I agree you can work with it.